# Getting imshow to display a separate colour per value in a 2D array in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm currently classifying an image and outputting a 2D array of values between 0 and 30.

Instead of using a default colour map, is it possible to get `imshow` to easily display a different colour per value? Possibly a set of selected colours?

I'm looking to highlight differences rather than having a smooth colour change. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you'll have to build a custom colormap with the number of colours equal to the number of values you want.

Comment: I had considered this, but was hoping there was a quicker way. Thank you

Comment: Look into the `BoundryNorm` and `NoNorm` normalization methods and search on discrete color maps.